# Eliminate list elements contained in another list

Tags: list, filter, ocaml

I have this code for eliminate a element where is contained in a list:

```
let remove_all x l = 
    let rec aux l acc = match l with
        [] -> List.rev acc
        | h::t when h=x -> aux t acc
        | h::t -> aux t (h::acc)
    in aux l [];;
```

Now i use this function to help the following code to eliminate list elements contained in another list:

```
let leliminate l1 l2 = 
    let rec aux l1 l2 acc = match (l1,l2) with
        ([],[]) -> acc
        | (h1::t1, h2::t2) when h1=h2 -> aux t1 l2 (remove_all h1 acc)
        | (h1::t1, h2::t2) when h1!=h2 -> aux t1 t2 acc
        | (h1::t1, []) -> aux t1 l2 acc
    in aux l1 l2 l1;;
```

The problem when i call:

```
leliminate [1;2;3;2;4] [2;3;3;5];;
```

is that the function returns [1;2;3;2;4] when i expect [1;4].

Comment: The problem is in the second pattern in `leliminate`’s match statement — can you see why? Try going through your example my hand

Answer (score 2):

Your function can be written slightly more succinctly using a few functions from the standard library:

```
let leliminate l1 l2 =
  List.filter (fun x -> not (List.mem x l2)) l1;;
```

Comment: I agree that this is a better alternative, but it doesn’t really answer OP’s question

Comment: @NickZuber Which part of the question does it not answer?

Comment: Hmm I guess he never actually _asked_ a question, but it was kinda implied he wanted to know why his code didn’t work properly

Comment: @NickZuber Or he's just trying to show that he's made an effort to solve the problem himself. Either is a fair interpretation I think :)